# Prove that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa} X_{\alpha} \preceq \kappa \times \kappa $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal number. Let $\{X_{\alpha} | \alpha \in \kappa \}$ be a set of pairwise disjoint sets. Show that if $X_\alpha \preceq \kappa$ for all oridinal numbers $\alpha \in \kappa$, then $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa} X_{\alpha} \preceq \kappa \times  \kappa $ The symbol $\preceq$ means that there is a one-to-one mapping.

EDIT:

But I am not quite sure what can I get from the condition pairwise disjoint sets

Is providing proof that the cardinality of $\bigcup_{\alpha \in \kappa} X_{\alpha}$ is less than $\kappa$ enough for this prrof?.

Comment: This is literally a two lines proof. The only thing you have to do, and can do, is to use the information given to you in the question. There is an injection into $\kappa$, there are $\kappa$ pairwise disjoint sets. Since there isn't even a question mark in this post, I'm not even sure what is the question.

Comment: The question is to show that  ⋃α∈κXα⪯κ×κ, but I am not quite sure what can I get from the condition pairwise disjoint sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think it is a question about the axiom of choice.

Comment: @William: Of course you *need* to use the axiom of choice here. But this is not a question *about* the axiom of choice. This is not even a question. Questions have question marks, or at least words like "how" or "why" or "what" to indicate that a question is being asked.

Comment: Yinan: Well, that information should go into the question, not into the comments. Preferably, before people ask in the comments "what is unclear about the problem that you have written above, without any indication as to what is unclear".

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $f$ and $g$ are functions whose domains are disjoint, then $f\cup g$ is a function.